# looking for approximation/expansion of $f(t)=a(t)/\sqrt{b(t) + \epsilon(t)}$ with $\epsilon(t) << b(t)$

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

I have the following function 
$
f(t) = \frac{a(t)}{\sqrt{b(t) + \epsilon(t)}}
$
defined for $t\geq 0$. I know that $a(t) > 0$, $b(t) > 0$, $\epsilon(t) \geq 0$ and $\epsilon(t) << b(t) $ $\forall t\geq0$ (and, in particular, $\epsilon(0) = 0$, whereas $b(0)=b_0 >> 0$).

What can I do to find an approximation/expansion for $f(t)$ leveraging on the small size of $\epsilon(t)$? May I use some sort of Taylor/Mac-Laurin expansion?
Or some functional-derivative like reasoning?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the expansion, valid as long as $|\epsilon|<b$, $$f=\frac{a}{\sqrt{b}}\left(1+\frac{\epsilon}b\right)^{-1/2}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{b}}{}{}{}{}\sum_{k\geqslant0}{-1/2\choose k}\left(\frac{\epsilon}b\right)^k.$$

Comment: Thanks @Did, so you suggest to express $f$ thorough its defining series and use the first few, say $n$ terms, leaving an error $O(\epsilon^{n+1})$. This sounds very straightforward (and basically, is what I had in mind...) but  are you sure shouldn't be more correct to use a functional derivative approach?